# Ajuda com sistema de níveis (RPG)

Tags: java, jogos

Olá, eu estou tentando construir um sistema de leveling (como um RPG). Até agora eu tenho isso:

```
Math.floor(1000 * Math.pow(level, 1.5F));
```

Aqui eu entro com o level, e consigo a EXP necessária para alcança-lo. Mas agora eu preciso fazer ao contrário, preciso entrar com a EXP e pegar o nível atual. Sou realmente ruim com matemática, alguém tem a minha solução?

Comment: Eu procurei e não achei, mas eu juro que lembro dessa *exata* pergunta por aqui. Talvez não tenha sido você quem postou, mas enfim, não achei mais. De todas as formas vc já teve a sua resposta (muito boa, ao ponto de que salvou a sua pergunta pelos detalhes do arredondamento - caso contrário a pergunta seria somente uma questão de matemática, e eu diria que estaria fora do escopo do site). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos começar com esse método:

```
public static int levelToExp(int level) {
    return (int) Math.floor(1000 * Math.pow(level, 1.5));
}
```

Essa fórmula pega o número `level`, eleva a 1.5, multiplica por 1000 e arredonda.

O inverso seria, ignorando-se o arredondamento no final, dividir por 1000 e elevar ao inverso de 1.5.

Qual é o inverso de 1.5? Bem, considerando que 1.5 = 3/2, então o inverso é 2/3.

Portanto, a fórmula seria algo **parecido** com isso:

```
Math.pow(exp / 1000.0, 2 / 3.0);
```

Por que **parecido**? Por que ainda temos que lidar com o arredondamento e com o erros que ele introduz. Por exemplo:

```
class TesteExp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int level = 2;
        int exp = (int) Math.floor(1000 * Math.pow(level, 1.5));
        System.out.println(exp);
        double level2 = Math.pow(exp / 1000.0, 2 / 3.0);
        System.out.println(level2);
        System.out.println(Math.floor(level2));
    }
}
```

Eis a saída ([veja aqui funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/XskqsK)):

```
2828
1.9997986463957098
1.0
```

Ou seja, para chegar-se ao level 2, é necessário ter-se 2828 pontos de EXP. Mas invertendo-se a equação, chega-se ao level 1.9997986463957098, que se arredondarmos para baixo daria level 1, e não 2. Isso ocorre porque a EXP necessária seria um número entre 2828 e 2829, mas o `Math.floor` a arredondou para baixo.

Se ao invés de arredondarmos o level para baixo, fôssemos arredondar para cima, também não daria certo porque no caso da quantidade de EXP ser 2827, ele estaria no level 2, ao invés do level 1.

Assim sendo, não sabemos ainda se devemos arredondar para cima ou para baixo. O que podemos fazer? Chutar as duas formas e ver qual dos levels correspondentes serve:

```
public static int expToLevel(int exp) {
    double level = Math.pow(exp / 1000.0, 2 / 3.0);
    int a = (int) Math.floor(level);
    int b = (int) Math.ceil(level);
    return levelToExp(b) > exp ? a : b;
}
```

Vamos testar esse código todo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        int exp = levelToExp(i);
        System.out.print("Para o level " + i + " precisamos de " + exp + " EXP. ");
        int provaReal = expToLevel(exp);
        int antes = expToLevel(exp - 1);
        int depois = expToLevel(exp + 1);
        System.out.print((exp - 1) + " EXP = Level " + antes + ". ");
        System.out.print(exp + " EXP = Level " + provaReal + ". ");
        System.out.print((exp + 1) + " EXP = Level " + depois + ".");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Eis a saída ([Veja aqui funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/p4w4bx)):

```
Para o level 0 precisamos de 0 EXP. -1 EXP = Level 0. 0 EXP = Level 0. 1 EXP = Level 0.
Para o level 1 precisamos de 1000 EXP. 999 EXP = Level 0. 1000 EXP = Level 1. 1001 EXP = Level 1.
Para o level 2 precisamos de 2828 EXP. 2827 EXP = Level 1. 2828 EXP = Level 2. 2829 EXP = Level 2.
Para o level 3 precisamos de 5196 EXP. 5195 EXP = Level 2. 5196 EXP = Level 3. 5197 EXP = Level 3.
Para o level 4 precisamos de 8000 EXP. 7999 EXP = Level 3. 8000 EXP = Level 4. 8001 EXP = Level 4.
Para o level 5 precisamos de 11180 EXP. 11179 EXP = Level 4. 11180 EXP = Level 5. 11181 EXP = Level 5.
Para o level 6 precisamos de 14696 EXP. 14695 EXP = Level 5. 14696 EXP = Level 6. 14697 EXP = Level 6.
Para o level 7 precisamos de 18520 EXP. 18519 EXP = Level 6. 18520 EXP = Level 7. 18521 EXP = Level 7.
Para o level 8 precisamos de 22627 EXP. 22626 EXP = Level 7. 22627 EXP = Level 8. 22628 EXP = Level 8.
Para o level 9 precisamos de 27000 EXP. 26999 EXP = Level 8. 27000 EXP = Level 9. 27001 EXP = Level 9.
Para o level 10 precisamos de 31622 EXP. 31621 EXP = Level 9. 31622 EXP = Level 10. 31623 EXP = Level 10.
Para o level 11 precisamos de 36482 EXP. 36481 EXP = Level 10. 36482 EXP = Level 11. 36483 EXP = Level 11.
Para o level 12 precisamos de 41569 EXP. 41568 EXP = Level 11. 41569 EXP = Level 12. 41570 EXP = Level 12.
Para o level 13 precisamos de 46872 EXP. 46871 EXP = Level 12. 46872 EXP = Level 13. 46873 EXP = Level 13.
Para o level 14 precisamos de 52383 EXP. 52382 EXP = Level 13. 52383 EXP = Level 14. 52384 EXP = Level 14.
Para o level 15 precisamos de 58094 EXP. 58093 EXP = Level 14. 58094 EXP = Level 15. 58095 EXP = Level 15.
Para o level 16 precisamos de 64000 EXP. 63999 EXP = Level 15. 64000 EXP = Level 16. 64001 EXP = Level 16.
Para o level 17 precisamos de 70092 EXP. 70091 EXP = Level 16. 70092 EXP = Level 17. 70093 EXP = Level 17.
Para o level 18 precisamos de 76367 EXP. 76366 EXP = Level 17. 76367 EXP = Level 18. 76368 EXP = Level 18.
Para o level 19 precisamos de 82819 EXP. 82818 EXP = Level 18. 82819 EXP = Level 19. 82820 EXP = Level 19.
Para o level 20 precisamos de 89442 EXP. 89441 EXP = Level 19. 89442 EXP = Level 20. 89443 EXP = Level 20.
```

Observe que a saída corresponde ao esperado. Com um ponto de EXP a menos, ele cai para o level anterior. Com um ponto de EXP a mais, ele continua no mesmo level.